# Double rendering in React with asynchronous call in componentDidMount causing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a blog application that has an articles index page, and from there you can click on an article to see the article or edit the article.

If you're going from the index page to the edit page, it works just fine because I already have all the articles in state. But if I refresh after I've gone to the edit-article page, I no longer have all the articles in state.

This is a problem because I'm making an asynchronous recieveSingleArticle call in the componentDidMount of my edit-article page, then I setState so my form is prepopulated. There's a double render which causes an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" error, presumably during the first render before the article has been received into state.

```
class ArticleEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {title: "", body: "", imageFile: ""};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePublish = this.handlePublish.bind(this);
    this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
    this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { article, requestSingleArticle } = this.props;

    requestSingleArticle(this.props.match.params.articleID)
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        title: article.title,
        body: article.body,
        imageFile: article.imageFile
      });
    });
  }
...
```

I tried wrapping my async calls inside of an "if (this.props.article)" but that didn't work. Is there a best way of dealing with this type of problem? Any advice greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Another solution that works is to have a componentDidUpdate in addition to componentDidMount. check in componentDidMount if this.props.article exists and if so, setState. And in componentDidUpdate, wrap the setState in the following conditional:

```
if (!prevProps.article && this.props.article)
```

Comment: try move the API call to `constructor` ;)

Comment: Are you perhaps using a router? You pass the id from the ArticleList into ArticleEdit as props. and when you refresh the (browser) Edit Page, no data will be fetch?. If so then the article id passed as props will be null hence making the http request fail

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Adding to my constructor certainly did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the article is present in the props before calling async action

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { article, requestSingleArticle } = this.props;
  if (!(article && requestSingleArticle)) return; // this line
  requestSingleArticle(this.props.match.params.articleID)
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({
      title: article.title,
      body: article.body,
      imageFile: article.imageFile
    });
  });
}
```

Since you are not getting any render from this method , it means that the props are not yet obtained in the life cycle method `componnetDidMount`. So instead you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp) {
  // this line here will check the article props' status so that
  // we will not use setState each time we get a prop
  if (this.props.article === nextProp.article) return;

  // rest is just the same code from above
  const { article, requestSingleArticle } = nextProp;
  if (!(article && requestSingleArticle)) return; // this line
  requestSingleArticle(this.props.match.params.articleID)
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({
      title: article.title,
      body: article.body,
      imageFile: article.imageFile
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this method, it doesn't prepopulate the form if you're refreshing the page from within the ArticleEdit page.

Comment: that is because there is no article in your prop when your component have just mounted.
Instead of `componentDidMount`, I think you should use `componentWillReceiveProps`. That way you are sure to get an article prop if it is sure to come within the component's lifetime

Comment: Ah componentWillReceiveProps worked! I suppose I might want to consider getDerivedStateFromProps as I move forward

Comment: @akorn3000 please mark the answer correct in that case! So that others facing the same problem know what solves their problem :)